# Some inputs disabled when checked option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i would like to add function to my form when i select one option then some inputs of my form are disabled i tried to do this in jquery but something is not working.Could u help me wit this?

There is a example form:

```
<div class="col-4">
   <label>Enabled </label>
   <select name="stato" id="stato" class="form-control">
      <option value="Text1">Text1</option>
      <option value="Text2">Text2</option>
      <option value="Text3">Text3</option>
      <option value="Text4">Text4</option>
   </select>
</div>
 
<div class="col-4" >
   <label>Disabled when choose option in select</label>
   <input id="data_consegna" type="text" class="form-control" name="data_consegna" placeholder="Data Consegna" />
</div>
```

and function in jquery

```
$(function() {
  $('#data_consegna').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#stato option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is('selected')) {
      $('#data_consegna').prop('enabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#data_consegna').prop('enabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You need a change event handler

Comment: Also, your code will only apply on the last option as that will overwrite any previous enabled true/false.  As you disable first, you could remove the "else disable".

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enter code here
```

```js
$(function() {
        //Triggering change event handler on element #stato
        $('#stato').change(function() {
            var value = $(this).val(); //Getting selected value from #stato
            if (value == "") {
                $('.common_disable').prop('disabled', false); //If value is empty then disable another field
            } else {
                $('.common_disable').prop('disabled', true); //Else enable another field
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-4">
   <label>Enabled </label>
   <select name="stato" id="stato" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select One</option>
        <option value="Text1">Text1</option>
        <option value="Text2">Text2</option>
        <option value="Text3">Text3</option>
        <option value="Text4">Text4</option>
   </select>
</div>
 
<div class="col-4" >
   <label>Disabled when choose option in select</label><br>
   <input id="data_consegna" type="text" class="form-control common_disable" name="data_consegna" placeholder="Data Consegna" /><br>
   <input id="data_consegna2" type="text" class="form-control common_disable" name="data_consegna2" placeholder="Data Consegna2" /><br>
   <input id="data_consegna3" type="text" class="form-control common_disable" name="data_consegna3" placeholder="Data Consegna3" /><br>
</div>
```

Please check above solution. It will enable input box at initial level. when you select one value, then it will disable input box.

Comment: Hi thanks for help it works. I wonder if i would add few more inputs to disable when select option is chosen how to make it? I know that i could add just input with the same id but what ,if i have inputs with diffrent id. Get this input by name or i need to change this code?

Comment: Give those all those inputs the same class and use `$(".toggle_class").prop...` (or whatever name you use), rather than use IDs.

Comment: Please see the updated codes. I've updated previous snippet. This one will serve your purpose :)